# Make command fails on Windows 7: recipe for target 'all-recursive' failed

Tags: windows, windows-7, installation, makefile, mingw

I am trying to install httperf on my Windows 7 machine and to do that I need to follow commands as below:

> Grab the latest, greatest tarball file (as of this writing, it’s 0.8),
>   su to root, mv the file to /usr/local/bin, and run the commands:
>
> tar xvzf httperf-0.8.tar.gz
>
> cd httperf-0.8
>
> ./configure
>
> make
>
> make install

To do all of that I had to install a MinGW. Unfortunately when I get to 'make', in this case when I run 'mingw32-make' I get the following error:

```
$ mingw32-make
making all in lib
      0 [main] make 8056 open_stackdumpfile: Dumping stack trace to make.exe.sta
ckdump
Makefile:68: recipe for target 'all-recursive' failed
mingw32-make: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
```

I am new to this so I would appreciate any help. I have changed the path to point to mingw\bin so all of this has been done but I really don't know what else this could be.
Also I tried running just 'make' and that did not do anything, just stopped everything without giving me an error.

Comment: It's hard to say without more information, could you dump the output of `mingw32-make -d` somewhere?

Comment: Hmm... not good. Make is crashing (hence the 'Dumping stack trace'). Which version of MinGW are you using? Are you running a 32-bit or 64-bit version of Windows? Also, the latest version of httperf is 0.9.0, which is available from here: http://code.google.com/p/httperf/downloads/list

Answer (score 1):

For Windows, httpperf is available pre-built with [Cygwin](https://www.cygwin.com/), if you can stomach hassle of installing it (tedious, more than difficult).

Some will talk about performance problems with Cygwin. This is generally misplaced; it's normally to do with the way Windows creates processes, which is very different to the way Unix/Linux does it, so it feels (is) slow when doing it on Cygwin, compared to Linux.

For what you want to do, the startup time should be irrelevant and the data you get from httperf "good enough" (compared to not being able to run it at all or running in a Linux VM...)